# Why doesn't my Rails engine mount under the correct path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails engine with these routes:

```
Project::Engine.routes.draw do
  post '/sessions' => 'project/sessions#create'
  get '/login'  => "project/sessions#new", as: :login
  get '/logout' => "project/sessions#destroy", as: :logout

  root to: 'project/home#dashboard'
end
```

In my main Rails app, I have the engine's routes mounted like this:

```
CMS::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Project::Engine => '/project', as: 'project'
end
```

I would think that this would mean that I would now have a `/project/login` route and `/project/logout` `/project/sessions` routes, but instead they are all under root(`/sessions`, `/login`, `/logout`).

If this isn't going to do what I want, then what exactly is going on here when I specify the path here?  I'm using Rails 4.2.1.

Comment: What does `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` show?

Answer (score 0):

I believe after testing that the problem is that you use 'project/[...]' when drawing the routes inside the engine. 
You mount the engine as project in the main app. Project is out of scope when referenced inside the engine.

Changing to the following should make it work.

```
Project::Engine.routes.draw do
  post '/sessions' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/login'  => "sessions#new", as: :login
  get '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", as: :logout

  root to: 'home#dashboard'
end
```

Then mounting the engine with:

```
CMS::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Project::Engine => '/project', as: 'project'
end
```

Gives the paths:

- /project
- /project/sessions
- /project/login
- /project/logout

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#mounting-the-engine
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes